# how to redirect to email id?

Tags: asp.net

i m using ASP.net C#and i m trying to make email verification with my web application.

how to send email verification to the client of my web application after registering into it.

could any one get idea about that??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class which allows you to send emails in .NET. There is an example in the documentation.